# iOS parse.com push error

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, error-handling, parse-platform

I have an array of string's that I am trying to save to parse as the channels for push notifications. The array is correct, put I have no idea what is going on. Can anybody throw some light on this? Thanks.

Error:

> Error: Bad channel name: TestString123 (Code: 112, Version: 1.1.30)

Code:

```
- (void)saveSelectedDepartmentsToParse:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary {

    NSArray *array = [dictionary allKeysForObject:@"YES"];

    NSLog(@"Array = %@", array);

    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

    [currentInstallation addObjectsFromArray:array forKey:@"channels"];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

        if (error == nil) {

            NSLog(@"Parse Save Succeeded");
        }
        else {

            NSLog(@"Parse Save Failed, %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because Parse does not accept whitespaces or any special characters in the channels. After removing all white spaces and special characters, the operation succeeded.